# CANopen NMT broadcast (using NodeId 0) support

Tags: ros, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering if there is a way to send NMT commands to all CANopen-nodes at once using NodeId = 0x00 (zero) as broadcast.

At first I thought canopen::NodeChain would do that but eg. canopen::NodeChain::start() is also iterating over its Node-objects calling start() for each node seperately.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229386/canopen-nmt-broadcast-(using-nodeid-0)-support/) by [JochenLg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26315/jochenlg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `ros_canopen` ROS nodes do not support NMT broadcasts. Each ROS node is just responsible for its configured CANopen nodes.
This limitation simplifies the management logic and enables to run multiple ROS nodes on the same bus (`SharedMaster` plugin). This way each CANopen node can be configured and managed individually.

If you really need NMT broadcasting you can inherit from `RosChain::ChainNode` and customize its behaviour.
However, the NMT message class is not exposed by intention: I don't see a benefit from broadcasting and it might not be safe to broadcast to a CAN bus without knowing the state of the CANopen nodes.
(Maybe I should even consider sending a stop to all configured node before initializing them.)

Feel free to open an issue on github with a more specific request and some explanations on your use case.
We could then figure out if some NMT interfaces could be exposed for easier customisation.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2016-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1